# Por qué este @OrderBy JPA Hibernate no ordena correctamente?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

En mi ejemplo, quiero enseñar todos los deportes, con sus respectivos deportistas. Quiero que al mostrar los deportes, los deportistas mostrados sean ordenados por su Id.

```
public class Deportes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DEPORTE_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "PRECIO")
    private Double precio;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deportes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    **@OrderBy("id desc")**
    private List<Deportista> deportistas = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class Deportista implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_DEPORTISTA")
    private int id;
```

La consola me muestra algunos deportes con sus deportistas ordenados, pero otros no. Alguna idea de donde puede estar el fallo?

```
Deportes [id=1, nombre=Futbol, precio=55.5, [Deportista [id=9, nombre=anto veliz, edad=51, deporte=1], Deportista [id=3, nombre=Ramon Salazar, edad=23, deporte=1], Deportista [id=7, nombre=Angela salas, edad=21, deporte=1]]]
Deportes [id=2, nombre=Baloncesto, precio=50.0, [Deportista [id=8, nombre=mar tota, edad=29, deporte=2], Deportista [id=5, nombre=Ainhoa CASAS, edad=28, deporte=2], Deportista [id=1, nombre=Sergio Dominguez, edad=24, deporte=2]]]
Deportes [id=3, nombre=Tennis, precio=61.9900016784668, [Deportista [id=6, nombre=Ricard Grau, edad=33, deporte=3], Deportista [id=4, nombre=Fer coas, edad=22, deporte=3], Deportista [id=2, nombre=Andres Fernandez, edad=20, deporte=3]]]
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: El título tambien se traduce, Sergio. Te ayudamos por ser la primera ;) Bienvenidx a SOes!